# Are the traditions of Ground Hog Day connected to those of Candlemas Day in Europe?

Tags: europe, festival, folklore

Today, the 2nd February was ***Ground Hog Day***. In Europe it was also ***Candlemas Day*** (the Feast of the Presentation of Jesus in the Temple).

Now there is a tradition in America that if the humble ground hog emerges from his burrow in sunshine, he/she quickly returns and winter too will return. But if it is a dull day, he/she remains outside on the basis that winter has ended.

Very similar folklore surrounds *Candlemas Day*, though it does not involve any rodent. It is expressed in England in a rhyme:

*If Candlemas Day be fair and bright*,

*Winter will have another fight*;

*But if Candlemas Day be dull and drear*,

*There'll be no more winter in the year*

So Ground Hog Day, and Candlemas Day are both celebrated on 2nd February, and in both cases, the weather is seen as being a pointer to the continuation of, or end to the winter.

**What is the connection between them?**

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace But it is the same idea. If it is a sunny day then winter will return - but dull and drab then winter is over. The American settlers may well have seen Candlemas Day as a Catholic festival, and hence beyond the pale of Puritans. It was certainly preserved in Anglicanism.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Point taken, I've changed the title.

Comment: I think the answer to the question is found on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day#cite_ref-9) and the [associated footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day#cite_note-9). The first recorded occurrence of Ground Hog Day explicitly recognizes the European tradition and links it to Candlemas.  VtC as trivial.

Comment: Well done. I normally look at Wikipedia, but this time didn't. And what might VtC be?

Comment: It is an acronym for Vote to Close.